# how to filter tally xml response based on voucher number?

Tags: xml, soap, tally

I am trying to retrieve only the sales records of specific 'Voucher Number' =5 by using below XML post request to tally.

```
<ENVELOPE>
<HEADER>
<VERSION>1</VERSION>
<TALLYREQUEST>EXPORT</TALLYREQUEST>
<TYPE>data</TYPE>
<ID>voucher register</ID>
</HEADER>
<BODY>
<DESC>
<STATICVARIABLES>
<SVCURRENTCOMPANY>Headers Software Solutions Pvt  Ltd</SVCURRENTCOMPANY>
<VoucherTypeName>Sales</VoucherTypeName>
<VoucherNumber>5</VoucherNumber>
<SVEXPORTFORMAT>$$SysName:XML</SVEXPORTFORMAT>
</STATICVARIABLES>
</DESC>
</BODY>
</ENVELOPE>
```

In XML Response I am receiving entire sales record from Voucher Number 1 to 600.

```
<ENVELOPE>
<HEADER>
    <VERSION>1</VERSION>
    <STATUS>1</STATUS>
</HEADER>
<BODY>
    <DESC>
        <STATICVARIABLES>
            <SVCURRENTCOMPANY>Headers Software Solutions Pvt  Ltd</SVCURRENTCOMPANY>
        </STATICVARIABLES>
    </DESC>
    <DATA>
        <TALLYMESSAGE xmlns:UDF="TallyUDF">
            <VOUCHER REMOTEID="eedb4478-88d5-4d8f-8444-9f852c2e8eca-00000001" VCHKEY="eedb4478-88d5-4d8f-8444-9f852c2e8eca-0000a7d0:00000008" VCHTYPE="Sales" ACTION="Create" OBJVIEW="Invoice Voucher View">
                <ADDRESS.LIST TYPE="String">
                    <ADDRESS>No. P-35, Kaligambal Nagar, Thirumullaivoyal</ADDRESS>
                    <ADDRESS>Chennai-600062</ADDRESS>
                </ADDRESS.LIST>
                <BASICBUYERADDRESS.LIST TYPE="String">
                    <BASICBUYERADDRESS>No. P-35, Kaligambal Nagar, Thirumullaivoyal</BASICBUYERADDRESS>
                    <BASICBUYERADDRESS>Chennai-600062</BASICBUYERADDRESS>
                </BASICBUYERADDRESS.LIST>
                <OLDAUDITENTRYIDS.LIST TYPE="Number">
                    <OLDAUDITENTRYIDS>-1</OLDAUDITENTRYIDS>
                </OLDAUDITENTRYIDS.LIST>
                <DATE>20170814</DATE>
                <GUID>eedb4478-88d5-4d8f-8444-9f852c2e8eca-00000001</GUID>
                <STATENAME>Tamil Nadu</STATENAME>
                <PARTYGSTIN>33AASCS5559D1Z1</PARTYGSTIN>
                <PARTYNAME>Shri Pavithra Auto Products Private Limited</PARTYNAME>
                <VOUCHERTYPENAME>Sales</VOUCHERTYPENAME>
                <REFERENCE>145355345</REFERENCE>
                <VOUCHERNUMBER>1</VOUCHERNUMBER>
                <PARTYLEDGERNAME>Shri Pavithra Auto Products Private Limited</PARTYLEDGERNAME>
                <BASICBASEPARTYNAME>Shri Pavithra Auto Products Private Limited</BASICBASEPARTYNAME>
                .
                .
                .
                .
                .
            </VOUCHER>
        </TALLYMESSAGE>
        .
        .
        .
        .
        .
        .
        .
        .
        <TALLYMESSAGE xmlns:UDF="TallyUDF">
            <VOUCHER REMOTEID="eedb4478-88d5-4d8f-8444-9f852c2e8eca-0000006d" VCHKEY="eedb4478-88d5-4d8f-8444-9f852c2e8eca-0000a851:00000008" VCHTYPE="Sales" ACTION="Create" OBJVIEW="Invoice Voucher View">
                <ADDRESS.LIST TYPE="String">
                    <ADDRESS>Plot No.3(SP), III Main Road, Ambattur Industrial Estate,Chennai-600058</ADDRESS>
                </ADDRESS.LIST>
                <BASICBUYERADDRESS.LIST TYPE="String">
                    <BASICBUYERADDRESS>Plot No.3(SP), III Main Road, Ambattur Industrial Estate,Chennai-600058</BASICBUYERADDRESS>
                </BASICBUYERADDRESS.LIST>
                <OLDAUDITENTRYIDS.LIST TYPE="Number">
                    <OLDAUDITENTRYIDS>-1</OLDAUDITENTRYIDS>
                </OLDAUDITENTRYIDS.LIST>
                <DATE>20171221</DATE>
                <GUID>eedb4478-88d5-4d8f-8444-9f852c2e8eca-0000006d</GUID>
                <STATENAME>Tamil Nadu</STATENAME>
                <PARTYNAME>WABCO INDIA LIMITED-Ambattur</PARTYNAME>
                <VOUCHERTYPENAME>Sales</VOUCHERTYPENAME>
                <REFERENCE>4900017337</REFERENCE>
                <VOUCHERNUMBER>600</VOUCHERNUMBER>
                <PARTYLEDGERNAME>WABCO INDIA LIMITED-Ambattur</PARTYLEDGERNAME>
                <BASICBASEPARTYNAME>WABCO INDIA LIMITED-Ambattur</BASICBASEPARTYNAME>
                .
                .
                .
                .
                .
                .
           </VOUCHER>
        </TALLYMESSAGE>

        <TALLYMESSAGE xmlns:UDF="TallyUDF">
            <COMPANY>
                <REMOTECMPINFO.LIST MERGE="Yes">
                    <NAME>eedb4478-88d5-4d8f-8444-9f852c2e8eca</NAME>
                    <REMOTECMPNAME>Headers Software Solutions Pvt  Ltd</REMOTECMPNAME>
                    <REMOTECMPSTATE>TamilNadu</REMOTECMPSTATE>
                </REMOTECMPINFO.LIST>
            </COMPANY>
        </TALLYMESSAGE>
    </DATA>
</BODY>
```

How do I apply filter condition in XML request to retrieve only the specific voucher number details?

These links doesn't help me.

[Needs to retrieve sales order details using xml request to Tally erp 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26278805/needs-to-retrieve-sales-order-details-using-xml-request-to-tally-erp-9)

[Tally Ledger Voucher XML Export](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35797540/tally-ledger-voucher-xml-export?rq=1)

Please help me. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XML request to Export vouchers from Tally ERP 9 for a specified **VoucherNumber and VoucherType**.

TODO: You must specify the VoucherNumber and VoucherType in the XML as marked with TODO.

```
<ENVELOPE>  
  <HEADER>  
    <VERSION>1</VERSION>  
    <TALLYREQUEST>  EXPORT</TALLYREQUEST>  
    <TYPE>COLLECTION</TYPE>  
    <ID>  RTSAllVouchers_FilterForVchNoAndVchType</ID>  
  </HEADER>  
  <BODY>  
    <DESC>  
      <STATICVARIABLES>  
        <SVEXPORTFORMAT>$$SysName:XML</SVEXPORTFORMAT>  
        <!-- TODO : Specify the VoucherNo -->  
        <RTS_KEY>VCH-INV-1</RTS_KEY>  
        <!-- TODO : Specify the VoucherType here -->  
        <RTS_VOUCHERTYPENAME>Sales</RTS_VOUCHERTYPENAME>  
      </STATICVARIABLES>  
      <TDL>  
        <TDLMESSAGE>  
          <!-- Retrieve all Vouchers for specified VoucherNo and VoucherType -->  
          <COLLECTION NAME="RTSAllVouchers_FilterForVchNoAndVchType" ISINITIALIZE="Yes">  
              <TYPE>Voucher</TYPE>  
              <FETCH>ALLLEDGERENTRIES.*</FETCH>  
              <FETCH>ALLINVENTORYENTRIES.*</FETCH>  
              <FILTER>RTS_FilterForVchNoAndVchType</FILTER>  
          </COLLECTION>  
          <VARIABLE NAME="RTS_KEY">  
            <TYPE> String</TYPE>  
          </VARIABLE>  
          <VARIABLE NAME="RTS_VOUCHERTYPENAME">  
            <TYPE>String</TYPE>  
          </VARIABLE>  
          <SYSTEM TYPE="FORMULAE" NAME="RTS_FilterForVchNoAndVchType">  
            $VoucherNumber = $$String:##RTS_KEY and $VoucherTypeName = $$String:##RTS_VOUCHERTYPENAME
          </SYSTEM>  
        </TDLMESSAGE>  
      </TDL>  
    </DESC>  
  </BODY>  
</ENVELOPE>
```

Remarks:
The filter condition is applied using the TDL variables which are enclosed with the TDLMESSAGE tag. The variables are RTS_KEY and RTS_VOUCHERTYPENAME.

XML tags to fetch / export data from Tally ERP 9
https://www.rtslink.com/articles/tally-xml-tags-export/

Comment: You saved me. How do I fetch particular entries instead of all other unwanted elements?

Answer (score 1):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ENVELOPE>
<HEADER>
<VERSION>1</VERSION>
<TALLYREQUEST>EXPORT</TALLYREQUEST>
<TYPE>Object</TYPE>
<SUBTYPE>VOUCHER</SUBTYPE>
<ID TYPE="Name">ID:{Enter MASTER ID here}</ID>
</HEADER>
<BODY>
<DESC>
<STATICVARIABLES>
<SVEXPORTFORMAT>$$SysName:XML</SVEXPORTFORMAT>
<SVCURRENTCOMPANY>{{COMPANYNAME}}</SVCURRENTCOMPANY>
</STATICVARIABLES>
<FETCHLIST>
    <FETCH>VoucherNumber</FETCH>
</FETCHLIST>
</DESC>
</BODY>
</ENVELOPE>
```

You would need the master ID of the voucher created with the voucher number 5.

Answer (score 0):

With a voucher's date and any other method (Eg., voucher number, reference or Narration), you could also retrieve the voucher via XML.

```
<ENVELOPE>
    <HEADER>
        <VERSION>1</VERSION>
        <TALLYREQUEST>EXPORT</TALLYREQUEST>
        <TYPE>Object</TYPE>
        <SUBTYPE>VOUCHER</SUBTYPE>
        <ID TYPE="Name">Date:'1-08-2019':VoucherNumber:'IN-12345'</ID>
    </HEADER>
    <BODY>
        <DESC>
            <STATICVARIABLES>
            <SVCURRENTCOMPANY>Company ABC</SVCURRENTCOMPANY>
                <SVEXPORTFORMAT>$$SysName:XML</SVEXPORTFORMAT>
            </STATICVARIABLES>
            <FETCHLIST>
                <FETCH>Date</FETCH>
                <FETCH>VoucherNumber</FETCH>
                <FETCH>VoucherTypeName</FETCH>
            </FETCHLIST>
        </DESC>
    </BODY>
</ENVELOPE>
```

source: https://help.tallysolutions.com/article/DeveloperReference/faq/6191.html

Comment: this request is throwing memory access violation error.

Comment: @VinodSai: this will throw an error if your company name is not correct. Else it should show the following message in case of an incorrect invoice-https://ibb.co/QnCvCW8. In case of a correct invoice, it will show the full xml.