# How to differentiate two nodes with their childs in a Tally XML string

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql, tally

I have XML is like this:

```xml
<ENVELOPE>
    <DSPACCNAME>
        <DSPDISPNAME>Opening Stock</DSPDISPNAME>
    </DSPACCNAME>
    <PLAMT>
        <PLSUBAMT/>
        <BSMAINAMT>-44912711.35</BSMAINAMT>
    </PLAMT>
    <BSNAME>
        <DSPACCNAME>
            <DSPDISPNAME>Stock-in-Hand-Accesories(KPM)</DSPDISPNAME>
        </DSPACCNAME>
    </BSNAME>
    <BSAMT>
        <BSSUBAMT>-15750.01</BSSUBAMT>
        <BSMAINAMT/>
    </BSAMT>
    <BSNAME>
        <DSPACCNAME>
            <DSPDISPNAME>Stock-in-Hand-Accesories(KVM)</DSPDISPNAME>
        </DSPACCNAME>
    </BSNAME>
    <BSAMT>
        <BSSUBAMT>-16750.01</BSSUBAMT>
        <BSMAINAMT/>
    </BSAMT>
    <DSPACCNAME>
        <DSPDISPNAME>Closing Stock</DSPDISPNAME>
    </DSPACCNAME>
    <BSNAME>
        <DSPACCNAME>
            <DSPDISPNAME>Stock-in-Hand-Accesories(KPM)</DSPDISPNAME>
        </DSPACCNAME>
    </BSNAME>
    <BSAMT>
        <BSSUBAMT>-54750.01</BSSUBAMT>
        <BSMAINAMT/>
    </BSAMT>
    <BSNAME>
        <DSPACCNAME>
            <DSPDISPNAME>Stock-in-Hand-Accesories(KRM)</DSPDISPNAME>
        </DSPACCNAME>
    </BSNAME>
    <BSAMT>
        <BSSUBAMT>-74750.01</BSSUBAMT>
        <BSMAINAMT/>
    </BSAMT>
</ENVELOPE>
```

My result should come as:

```
Opening Stock   Stock-in-Hand-Accesories(KPM)   -15750.01
Opening Stock   Stock-in-Hand-Accesories(KVM)   -16750.01
Closing Stock   Stock-in-Hand-Accesories(KPM)   -54750.01
Closing Stock   Stock-in-Hand-Accesories(KRM)   -74750.01
```

Comment: Is that an XML column or an XML variable?

Comment: Not sure I understand. The value of `BSSUBAMT` and `DSPDISPNAME` aren't related in that XML; they aren't in the same node. If they are related they should share a common parent node (that isn't the root note).

Comment: Why should `Opening Stock` be associated wtih `-15750.01` instead of `-54750.01`? There's *nothing* that says they're related. If that `Envelope` is supposed to contain two records, I'd say the design is *very* bad and needs to be fixed

Comment: There's no 'but that's what I got`, in XML those elements have nothing in common except the root element. Their order, or the fact that they get repeated doesn't count. That's not how XML is supposed to work.

Comment: Is the PLAMT node always going to be there?

Comment: This *string* will need transforming before it can be treated as XML. Eg you can replace `<DSPACCNAME>` with `<record><DSPACCNAME>` and `</BSAMT>` with `</BSAMT></record>` to convert the string to parsable XML

Comment: Perhaps if your XML was more like [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=cdf3ed0585bfd927a73f5be05f05bbfc) it would be easier. :/

Comment: Are you trying to work with *Tally*? In that case you should make that clear, there may be others that have found a way to work with this product and the .... idiosyncratic XML syntax. It would also make it clear that the author of the string isn't going to fix it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the only relation is the order of nodes, you can select all `BSNAME` nodes as anchors, and use the [`>>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/xquery/comparison-expressions-xquery?view=sql-server-2017#node-order-comparison-operators) and `<<` operator to find nearest `BSAMT` and `DSPACCNAME` nodes:

```sql
DECLARE @xml XML = '<ENVELOPE>
    <DSPACCNAME>
        <DSPDISPNAME>Opening Stock</DSPDISPNAME>
    </DSPACCNAME>
    <PLAMT>
        <PLSUBAMT/>
        <BSMAINAMT>-44912711.35</BSMAINAMT>
    </PLAMT>
    <BSNAME>
        <DSPACCNAME>
            <DSPDISPNAME>Stock-in-Hand-Accesories(KPM)</DSPDISPNAME>
        </DSPACCNAME>
    </BSNAME>
    <BSAMT>
        <BSSUBAMT>-15750.01</BSSUBAMT>
        <BSMAINAMT/>
    </BSAMT>
    <BSNAME>
        <DSPACCNAME>
            <DSPDISPNAME>Stock-in-Hand-Accesories(KVM)</DSPDISPNAME>
        </DSPACCNAME>
    </BSNAME>
    <BSAMT>
        <BSSUBAMT>-16750.01</BSSUBAMT>
        <BSMAINAMT/>
    </BSAMT>
    <DSPACCNAME>
        <DSPDISPNAME>Closing Stock</DSPDISPNAME>
    </DSPACCNAME>
    <BSNAME>
        <DSPACCNAME>
            <DSPDISPNAME>Stock-in-Hand-Accesories(KPM)</DSPDISPNAME>
        </DSPACCNAME>
    </BSNAME>
    <BSAMT>
        <BSSUBAMT>-54750.01</BSSUBAMT>
        <BSMAINAMT/>
    </BSAMT>
    <BSNAME>
        <DSPACCNAME>
            <DSPDISPNAME>Stock-in-Hand-Accesories(KRM)</DSPDISPNAME>
        </DSPACCNAME>
    </BSNAME>
    <BSAMT>
        <BSSUBAMT>-74750.01</BSSUBAMT>
        <BSMAINAMT/>
    </BSAMT>
</ENVELOPE>';
SELECT refnode.value('(./DSPACCNAME/DSPDISPNAME)[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS [BSNAME]
     , refnode.value('let $c := . return (../BSAMT[. >> $c]/BSSUBAMT)[1]', 'DECIMAL(18,2)') AS [BSAMT]
     , refnode.value('let $c := . return (../DSPACCNAME[. << $c]/DSPDISPNAME)[last()]', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS [DSPACCNAME]
FROM @xml.nodes('//ENVELOPE/BSNAME') x(refnode)
```

[Demo on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=53cf0d467bd575efcab69bc7276b05f0)

Comment: Given that top-level nodes also appear under child nodes, order is probably the only way to parse this

Comment: I'm afraid that this *string* is actually some ERP vendor's idea of what an XML export format should look like. As for their SOAP API [....](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48965228/how-to-filter-tally-xml-response-based-on-voucher-number)

Comment: This is ok but I need the data based on BSNAME not in the sense of DSPACCNAME

Answer (score 0):

While this was okay to do as Salman A has suggested, it is highly susceptible to errors. It looks like this XML was formed with a custom TDL (Tally add-on). In this case, I agree with Panagiotis Kanavos that the XML is not properly formed. You can have the TDL developer simply re-arrange the XML tags by putting an XML tag at the 'Line' Level for every parent node, and at the 'Field' Level for every child node. Note that the Line must be repeated using 'Repeat' variable for multiple parent nodes with child nodes to come up in the XML.

You can refer this [reference guide](http://mirror1.tallysolutions.com/Downloads/TDL%20Developer/Tally.ERP%209%20-%20Integration%20Capabilities.pdf), specifically the section 2.2.5 , on how to use XML tags.