# Verify vouchers integrated into tally from staging table

Tags: integration, tally

If I have 5 vouchers in SQL server database staging table and I imported all 5 vouchers in tally using tally XML API.

How can I verify and cross check the vouchers between tally and SQL using only voucher number?

Do I have to read entire voucher summary from tally and then extract voucher numbers from the XML data ? After extracting voucher numbers I can compare it to staging table.

How can I just export only voucher number or one specific field from a report in tally ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you know the voucher number after importing into Tally? Depending on the answer to this, I'll update my answer.

**Case 1:** If you do know the voucher number, you can use Tally XML to request for that particular voucher number and if you get a positive response, then that voucher exists in tally. No need to read voucher summary. You'll just need to look for a particular element tag in XML response - if that element exists = voucher exists.

**Case 2:** But I assume you don't know the voucher number that was created during the import. In that case. It'll be a bit more tricky. Let me know and I'll update with whatever solution I have.

**--Update--**

After discussing (see comments), I'm updating the answer as per Case 1.
XML Request Structure -

```
<ENVELOPE>
  <HEADER>
    <VERSION>1</VERSION>
    <TALLYREQUEST>EXPORT</TALLYREQUEST>
    <TYPE>COLLECTION</TYPE>
    <ID>FindParticularVoucher</ID>
  </HEADER>
  <BODY>
    <DESC>
      <STATICVARIABLES>
        <SVEXPORTFORMAT>$$SysName:XML</SVEXPORTFORMAT>
        <SVCURRENTCOMPANY>FOO COMPANY</SVCURRENTCOMPANY>
        <VCHNO>ABC1234</VCHNO>
      </STATICVARIABLES>
      <TDL>
        <TDLMESSAGE>
          <COLLECTION NAME="FindParticularVoucher" ISINITIALIZE="YES">
            <TYPE>Voucher</TYPE>
            <FILTER>GetInvoiceVoucher</FILTER>
          </COLLECTION>
          <VARIABLE NAME="VCHNO">
            <TYPE>String</TYPE>
          </VARIABLE>
          <SYSTEM TYPE="FORMULAE" NAME="GetInvoiceVoucher">$VoucherNumber = $$String:##VCHNO</SYSTEM>
        </TDLMESSAGE>
      </TDL>
    </DESC>
  </BODY>
</ENVELOPE>
```

Remember to change the Company name & Voucher Number within the **SVCURRENTCOMPANY** and **VCHNO** Xml Tags.

You might get a complex XML Response. All you need to do is look for the XML Node named Voucher within the Collection Node - Envelope/Body/Data/Collection/Voucher. If this VoucherNode exists = your voucher exists in tally. In this case you don't need to export any data or the voucher number.

Comment: Since I'm integrating data into fresh setup I can have manual voucher numbers defined in the staging table, but that might conflict if anyone does a manual entry and consumes the next voucher number in staging. So I guess I should create a new separate column in tally for holding voucher numbers coming from staging. Whats your take? Thanks.

Comment: If you do that, it'll definitely make things simpler since you'll be choosing your own voucher numbers. You can search for that particular voucher, using XML Request. I'll update my answer according to this.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a voucher using XML in Tally, you would get a XML response on successful creation. That response has a tag for, among other things, the voucher number that you  have given, and a LASTVCHID. This is like the master ID in tally. It's then easier to just request that master id and check the response. It would give an error if it doesn't find that master id (best of all, the error is just a one line XML response so no parsing required).

Check out this stackoverflow link for more details - [how to filter tally xml response based on voucher number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48965228/how-to-filter-tally-xml-response-based-on-voucher-number)