# Tally XML to get Single Accounting Voucher

Tags: xml, tally

I tried many ways but getting only an empty voucher. Added id field and used the voucher number but still, it shows an empty voucher. Can anyone help to get the single Accounting Voucher(Sales Voucher)? Basically I need the invoice of the voucher.

```
<ENVELOPE>
    < HEADER >
    <TALLYREQUEST>Export Data</TALLYREQUEST>
    </HEADER>
  <BODY><EXPORTDATA>
    <REQUESTDESC>
      <STATICVARIABLES>
        <SVCURRENTCOMPANY>COMPANY NAME</SVCURRENTCOMPANY>   
        <SVFROMDATE>20200206</SVFROMDATE>
        <SVTODATE>20200206</SVTODATE>
        <SVEXPORTFORMAT>$$SysName:html</SVEXPORTFORMAT>

      </STATICVARIABLES>
      <REPORTNAME>ACCOUNTING VOUCHER</REPORTNAME>
    </REQUESTDESC>
  </EXPORTDATA>
  </BODY>
  </ENVELOPE >
```

This is the response

[image]

Comment: Is it important to get a reply as HTML? Is it ok if you get it as an XML? If so, I can provide a solution.

Answer (score 0):

This XML request looks like it has been written for a report - do you want a report or a single voucher?

In case you need a single voucher, you can refer [this stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48965228/how-to-filter-tally-xml-response-based-on-voucher-number).

And if you need a report, you need to change report name to 'Voucher Register'

```
<REPORTNAME>Voucher Register</REPORTNAME>
```

Here's how the output would look - https://ibb.co/j38cGZj